# Need to collate information from array in python, by finding match values that lie in different rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I'm looking to collate 2 entries into one for many columns in a data array, by checking to see if several values in the two entries are the same.

```
0  A             [[0.0,    0.5,    2.5,    2.5]
1  B              [0.5,    1.0,    2.0,    2.0]
2  M              [2.5,    2.5,    0.5,    0.0]
3  N              [2.0,    2.0,    1.0,    0.5]
4  R              [14.3,   13.8,   13.9,   14.2]]
```

Above shows the format the array takes, with the numbering and annotation of the rows on the left. Each column in the array is one distinct measurement.

Rows 0-3 are the x-locations along a straight line of 2 pairs of electrodes used to make a measurement (pair 1 = A & B, pair 2 = M & N); R is the measured resistivity when the four electrodes above it are used. As can be seen, in the 1st and 4th measurement, pair AB of measurement 1 = pair MN of measurement 4, and vice versa. The same is true of the 2nd and 3rd reading.

What I'm trying to do is to search through the array to find each pair of measurements, then collate that into one entry. This entry would take the first measurement's electrode locations (A,B,M &N), together with the first measurement's R value, but would also contain an extra row with the second measurement's R value. The result from the example above can be seen below.

```
0  A             [[0.0,    0.5]
1  B              [0.5,    1.0]
2  M              [2.5,    2.5]
3  N              [2.0,    2.0]
4  R1             [14.3,   13.8]
5  R2             [13.9,   14.2]]
```

Some information that may be useful:
The numbers are floats
The first set of measurements (i.e. before there will be any pairs) are in the first half of the dataset. What I mean by that is if there was an array with 100 columns(equalling 100 measurements), the columns 51-100 would be the pairs of the columns 1-50. The columns 51-100 do not follow the same pattern as the columns 1-50 though (i.e. column 1 wouldn't always equal column 51 in that example).
The electrodes do always follow the same pattern in the pair of measurements; "A" in measurement 1 will always = "M in measurement 2 in the pair, equally B = N, M = A & N = B.

I've been thinking bout how to do it, and I've thought that some kind of if statement such as the one below may be a start, but really I'm a complete novice, and this is quite a complex problem to search for an answer.

```
if all(A1 == M2, B1 == N2, M1 == A2, N1 == B2):
```

Any help would be really appreciated, even if it's just a pointer to wherever would be a good starting point to search for more information.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Just to clarify, the order of R2 is liable to change for each dataset, and isn't the same as the order of R1. What I'm after doing is querying the A, B, M & N values to find the pairs of readings, then adding the paired R2 reading under its corresponding R1 reading.

Here is an example dataset that is a little larger:

```
#Input array
Arr1  =
[[0.5,  0.5,  1,    1,    1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  5,    4.5,  4.5,  3.5,  2.5,  2,    1]
 [0,    0,    0.5,  0.5,  1,    1,    0.5,  5.5,  5,    5.5,  4,    3,    2.5,  1.5]
 [1,    3.5,  2.5,  5,    2,    4.5,  4.5,  1,    1.5,  1.5,  0.5,  1,    1.5,  0.5]
 [1.5,  4,    3,    5.5,  2.5,  5,    5.5,  0.5,  1,    0.5,  0,    0.5,  1,    0]
 [14.3, 13.3, 25.1, 17.2, 19.9, 15.4, 16.1, 17.1, 15.3, 16.1, 13.4, 25.1, 19.8, 14.4]]

#Output array - extra R row and half the columns
Arr2 =
[[0.5,  0.5,  1,    1,    1.5,  1.5,  1.5]
 [0,    0,    0.5,  0.5,  1,    1,    0.5]
 [1,    3.5,  2.5,  5,    2,    4.5,  4.5]
 [1.5,  4,    3,    5.5,  2.5,  5,    5.5]
 [14.3, 13.3, 25.1, 17.2, 19.9, 15.4, 16.1]
 [14.4, 13.4, 25.1, 17.1, 19.8, 15.3, 16.1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to find the index of each R2 value that you're after and create the final transformation to your specifications, edited based on our earlier dialogue in the comments below:

```
#Input array
Arr1  = [[0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 5, 4.5, 4.5, 3.5, 2.5, 2, 1],
         [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 5.5, 5, 5.5, 4, 3, 2.5,  1.5],
         [1, 3.5, 2.5, 5, 2, 4.5, 4.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 0.5],
         [1.5, 4, 3, 5.5, 2.5, 5, 5.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0],
         [14.3, 13.3, 25.1, 17.2, 19.9, 15.4, 16.1,
          17.1, 15.3, 16.1, 13.4, 25.1, 19.8, 14.4]]

#Output array - extra R row and half the columns
Arr2 = [[0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
        [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5],
        [1, 3.5, 2.5, 5, 2, 4.5, 4.5],
        [1.5, 4, 3, 5.5, 2.5, 5, 5.5],
        [14.3, 13.3, 25.1, 17.2, 19.9, 15.4, 16.1],
        [14.4, 13.4, 25.1, 17.1, 19.8, 15.3, 16.1]]

# get the first half of each list in Arr1
half_1 = [i[:len(i)//2] for i in Arr1[:-1]]

# 'flip' the arrays so that there's a list for each element 0, 1, ...
half_1_flip = [[i[j] for i in half_1] for j in range(len(half_1[0]))]

# get the second half of each list in Arr1
half_2 = [i[len(i)//2:] for i in Arr1[:-1]]

# 'rotate' the arrays so that A / B and M / N switch places
half_2_rotate = half_2[len(half_2)//2:] + half_2[:len(half_2)//2]

# 'flip' the arrays so that there's a list for each element 0, 1, ...
half_2_flip = [[i[j] for i in half_2_rotate]
                         for j in range(len(half_2_rotate[0]))]

# find each matching index of the first flipped list in the second list
seek_indices = [half_2_flip.index(a) for i, a in enumerate(half_1_flip)]

# pull out original R1 and R2
r1 = Arr1[-1][:len(Arr1[-1])//2]
r2 = Arr1[-1][len(Arr1[-1])//2:]

# reorder R2 based on indices
ordered_r2 = [r2[i] for i in seek_indices]

# get final transform
transform = half_1 + [r1] + [ordered_r2]

assert transform == Arr2
```

Comment: Thanks, but this one doesn't work as it just adds the R2 values without changing their order. What I'm really after is querying the A, B, M & N values to inform which order the R2 value should be placed. Cheers for your help though!

Comment: @georussell Ah, so what exactly goes into the determination of order for R2?

Comment: The datasets consist of x measurements, in which there are x/2 pairs of measurements

A measurement pair is one where A & B in the first measurement == M & N in the second measurement, and M & N in the first measurement == A & B in the second measurement. (This is due to the pair being a forward and a reverse measurement).

The first half of the dataset contains the forward measurements, which are well ordered, the second half contains their pairs - but in a random order. I want to n=match the R1 the R2 values and re-order them so A1==M2, B1==N2, M1==A2 and N1==B2, as your edit shows above

Comment: One thing I was thinking, was utilising the order in the first half of the measurements. They are ordered by A increasing, if A is the same then B decreasing, then if A and B are the same M increasing. Maybe I could split the list in two, then apply the ordering to the second half of the measurements (so M inc., N dec. then A inc.) and take the R values and append them onto the first array. I'm not quite sure how to go about that at the minute though, just looking into it now.

Comment: @georussell Maybe you could provide an example of the unordered input, and an example of the desired output for it and for the associated R values?

Comment: Good idea. I've added an example dataset into an edit at the end of my original post.

Comment: @georussell I've edited my answer to give the correct output for your new example dataset. Hope it works for you!

Comment: This is great, thanks very much! I think I would have taken weeks getting there by myself! Sorry that the original question didn't get my point across, but thanks for perservering @alec

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to the problem might be slicing the data using the following function:

```
 import numpy as np

 def transform(arr):
     arr1 = arr[:,0:2]
     arr1 = np.append(arr1,[arr[-1,2:]],axis=0)
     return arr1
```

using given data:

```
 arr = np.array([[0.0,    0.5,    2.5,    2.5],
 [0.5,    1.0,    2.0,    2.0],
 [2.5,    2.5,    0.5,    0.0],
 [2.0,    2.0,    1.0,    0.5],
 [14.3,   13.8,   13.9,   14.2]])
```

`transform(arr)` returns:

```
 array([[  0. ,   0.5],
        [  0.5,   1. ],
        [  2.5,   2.5],
        [  2. ,   2. ],
        [ 14.3,  13.8],
        [ 13.9,  14.2]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. this seems to just move the R2 values into a new row without changing their order, where what I'm really after is querying the A, B, M & N values to order the R2 values (meaning 14.2 would be in column 1, and 13.9 would be in column 2 in this example). Thanks for trying to help though!